# How to change extjs grid row color

Tags: extjs

I want to change the color of the row in a extjs-3.1 grid from default to "dark red", When i either hover my mouse on row or i select a row , Please help.

Answer (score 2):

```
.x-grid3-row-selected {    
    background-color:red !important;
}
```

This will change the selected color to red.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by setting the background color of each column's renderer function.