# ExtJS 4 Ext.grid.Panel selection color

Tags: javascript, css, extjs, extjs4

I'm using ExtJs 4.1.3 and I have a simple grid (Ext.grid.Panel).
I want to change the color of selected rows in that grid from default selection color to "red".
I prefer do it in css file.
I've already tried solution in other threads (for example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3944139/how-to-change-extjs-grid-row-color)), but they don't work with extjs 4.

This is how is rendered a selected row with extjs 4:
[image: desc]
Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
.x-grid-row-selected .x-grid-cell-inner {
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color:red;
}
```

Comment: thank you! this help me a lot, however i suggest to edit this: .x-grid-row-selected .x-grid-cell, .x-grid-row-selected .x-grid-rowwrap-div